# outside for loop var value is undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm facing a problem with a value where inside my for cycle it has values like "179" and outside i get always undefined. Why?

```
var countRepetidos;
if(obj.data.list!={} && obj.data.list.length>0){    
    var aux = obj.data["list"];
    countRepetidos=0;
    for(var i=0;i<aux.length;i++){                              
       Database.Probing.getMacAdress(aux[i]).then(function(data){
            if(data.count>0){
               countRepetidos++;  
               console.log("count repetidos 1",countRepetidos); // value 116
            }                                   
        });
    }
    resolve(countRepetidos);
}   

console.log("count repetidos 2",countRepetidos);    // value undefined
```

log :

```
3|wscontro | count repetidos 1 116
3|wscontro | count repetidos 2 undefined
```

I try instead of use resolve, use callback but nothing... I saw other answers in javascript but for node.js I cant resolve this problem... I saw the link refering thus question as a duplicate but cant figure out a solution to this case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, its asynchronous. You have no problem with your code..the part with the console runs before the callback is done and then it goes to the callback.

Comment: The problem is I need this value to after insert in my array and do dataRepeated = [obj.data.stats.since, countRepetidos];

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a return in `if` statement. So if your code goes into the `if` scope then it will exit with `return resolve(countRepetidos)` and never reach the `console.log` statement. And if your code does not meet the condition of `if` then the value of `countRepetidos` will not be set and it will print `undefined`.

Also, due to your code being async, you will not be able to `resolve` proper count. To solve it you can do the following -

```
var countRepetidos;
var countPromises = []
if(obj.data.list!={} && obj.data.list.length>0){    
    var aux = obj.data["list"];
    countRepetidos=0;
    for(var i=0;i<aux.length;i++){                              
       countPromises.push(Database.Probing.getMacAdress(aux[i]).then(function(data){
            if(data.count>0){
               countRepetidos++;
               return Promise.resolve();
            }                                   
        }));
    }
    Promise.all(countPromises).then(() => {
        console.log(countRepetidos);
        resolve(countRepetidos));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kyBG3iWMjhv4qG4H4ZJ8?p=catalogue

Ok I'm confused... I need to verify my data.list before iterate over it

Comment: @AndréBastos If you're still putting the `console.log` outside if, you will still get `undefined`, however the code should now resolve correct data. If you want to `console.log`, do it in the `then` of `Promise.all`. (see updated answer)

Comment: it's still undefined